# How to migrate from Business Objects 6.5 to SAP BusinessObjects 4.1?

Tags: business-objects

In my organisation, Business Objects 6.5 is being used which is no longer supported by SAP. So I want to migrate to new web based reporting platform SAP BusinessObjects 4.1. How to perform this migration?

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty huge question.  I would start by reading the *Business Intelligence Platform Upgrade Guide* on help.sap.com.

**Edit based on comment**
I would suggest reaching out to your SAP account executive.  It's *possible* that they might give you a temporary license for XI3 so you can complete your migration.  (I don't know of any cases where they've done this, but considering that XI3 is out of mainstream support and this is your only upgrade path, I would hope that they would help you out).

If all you have to upgrade is universes, then you don't actually need to do the intermediate step.  Just use UDT in BI4 to open the .unv files and export them to the CMS.  Before doing this, you'll need to open the universes in Designer (6.5.1), and do a Save As with "Save for all users" checked off.

If you're migrating Full Client reports, then I *think* you can use the Report Conversion Tool in BI4.1 to convert the .rep files.  I haven't actually tried converting 6.5.1 .reps directly, but it might work.

In BI4.1, you can create an import file for users.  So, if you have a large number of users to import, you could export the list from Supervisor, massage the file, then import it with the CMC in BI4.1.  You'll need to manually create the groups and assign security.

If you have WebI reports, or a large number of Full Client documents in the repository, you'll need the intermediate step.

Comment: Yes, I can understand. But in most of the blogs it is said that only approach is to migrate to 3.x version first then 4.x version. So looking for suggestions that is more cost effective.

Comment: What is your cost concern?

Comment: I want to reuse my components (universe, report) in SAP BO 4.1 that were developed in BO 6.5

Comment: I understand, but you said you were looking for solutions that were "cost effective".  I'm wondering what exactly your concern is with the intermediate step to XI3?  Software licenses?  Resource time?

Comment: First is extra software license for XI3 then resource time is secondary concern. Anyways what do you suggest in this situation ?